# Use Stand Mixer for Scone

Tags: stand-mixer, scones

I tried for the first time to bake scone. I used a stand mixer to mix the ingredients based on a recipe. But I have some questions:

- Is it ok to use a stand mixer to mix them? I used the beater to mix them as it did it very quick.
- The dough was very runny and I was not able to shape it at all. I added more flour (I used self-raising) but it did not help.
- After I baked it, the smell and taste were good but they were not crumbly. They were more bread than scone as they were stiff. Did I mix for too long?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Scones should really be mixed very minimally, in order to avoid developing the gluten structure.  Over mixing will result in less crumbly end product.  So, in this instance I would not recommend a stand mixer.  Instead, just mix by hand.