# Best mixer for large amounts of scone dough

Tags: stand-mixer, scones

Which is the best mixer to use for large quantities of scone dough? I've researched Spiral mixers and they seem like the best option perhaps. I usually mix everything by hand but I'd like to scale my business and would like to make up to 12 batches at a time. Also with making larger quantities is there a formula that should be used to alter the rising agent, baking powder in particular? thx!

Comment: Welcome to SA!  It would really help with your question if you linked to a recipe that was similar to the kinds of scones you make.  The term "scone" can refer to several different baked goods depending on country.  Also, it would let people know how large a "batch" is.

Comment: Oh, and finally ... please ask your questions about mixers, and about scaling leavening agents, separately.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/107465/use-stand-mixer-for-scone - personally I woulnd't use any kind of mixer for scones. The dough for scones should not be kneaded or overworked, because that will develop the gluten leading to tough scones that will not rise properly. If any automation is used it would have to be quite brief, merely enough to bring the ingredients together.

Comment: Not a duplicate; Gretchen is asking about scaling a recipe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on my professional experience of making 2000 scones* a week for a bakery in Los Angeles:

If you're in North America, [get a Hobart](https://www.hobartcorp.com/products/food-prep/mixers).  They're quite expensive, so your best bet is to shop restaurant resales and auctions for a used one -- they're also very durable.  If you're in another country, find your region's equivalent professional-bakery-grade mixer.  A home-kitchen mixer won't last, and could easily die on you in a few months.

You do *not* want a spiral mixer.  Spiral mixers are designed for kneading yeasted doughs with a lot of gluten development, like breads and pizza dough.  With scones, you do not want gluten development.  On the Hobart, you would use the ["flat beater" mixer attachment](https://www.webstaurantstore.com/hobart-equivalent-aluminum-flat-beater-for-classic-mixers-60-qt-bowls/190HCM60FB.html), not the dough hook.

If you supply the details about actual batch size, I could even recommend a specific Hobart model.

(* this is the American definition of scones which is a large, sweetened shortbread, and not the British ones, which are more like what Americans call "biscuits" and not at all like what the British call "biscuits")

Comment: Thank you for this information. The commercial kitchen I use has a Hobart mixer with the flat beater attachment. I've tried making 64 scones at one time but noticed the bottom of the bowl wasn't incorporated so I needed to empty it all out on the work table to mix in by hand. Maybe that is what is expected?

Comment: One batch is 8 scones - 370 grams of flour

Comment: I would like to make 100-200 scones at a time if possible.